# Running Monocon-Pytorch on VM Training stuck at Epoch 1/150

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch

I am trying to run the monocon model
https://github.com/2gunsu/monocon-pytorch/blob/main/README.MD
I have set uploaded the training data to the VM and also set up everything correctly. However when I run the train.py, the training gets stuck at Epoch 1/150, after a long wait time, the program will be "killed" What could be the possible causes for this issue?

Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kKFX.png)

Trying to run the Monocon Model

Comment: Please post the error as text, not a screenshot.